# Centralized OLTP database design with OLAP layer

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, database-schema, data-warehouse

I'm doing a project and I'm not an expert on databases so I run into a few problems. In the architecture I'm thinking there are several small databases (single workstations) that push data into one big centralized Database, which stores those data in tables and only the records are added every time data is pushed. 
It would be helpful to analyze those data,but it is necessary for the central database to be OLTP (down-time is not viable because it's a medical record and must be up at all times) so is it possible that the OLAP is another layer above the centralized database and when analyzing doesn't interfere in the exchange of data between these singular workstations and the central database? Or does the central database need to be of OLAP architecture itself? Also can an OLTP database store for example data like medical history? (I'm asking because that data could be historical data as well, previous diseases etc. so I don't really understand how it would look like in tables). 
What would be the requirements for such an architecture? (let's say for a whole city, data consists of mostly txt and links). thanks for the help in advance guys, hope I was clear enough :)

Ps. By the way, this would be a central DB storing electronic health records of patients, which would be pushed by several doctors practices and clinics after a patients visit, or new diagnosis. So the exchange of data would be bi-directional, from the single workstations to the central db and the other way around (if doctors needed info from other doctors). Do you know of a better architecture for this? If we wanted to analyze those data i think this is the only viable option, but then again, i'm no expert so can't say much, let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 1):

As Neil has already said, normalization is a key principle (no pun intended) for good design in an OLTP environment.  Some other design principle is the key for a good data warehouse or data mart.  A data mart can serve as the base for OLAP operations.

Typically, OLAP doesn't require current data.  Once a day update is usually sufficient, and sometimes it could be as rare as once a month.  You know your requirements in your case.  The process of copying data from the operational (OLTP) database to the analytical (OLAP) database is known as Extract, Transform, and Load (ETL).  ETL processing can be quite intricate and involve a lot of programming, although there are tools out there to help build ETL processes.  You can't actually build the ETL until you've settled on the design of both the OLTP and OLAP databases, but you can plan ahead, and design things so that they all work together.

Sometimes, the OLAP database isn't in a relational (SQL) database at all, but in some specialized form, generally called a "data cube".  Analyzers that specialize in so called "business intelligence" often use data cubes, and sometimes these formats are proprietary and bound to the tool.

When the OLAP database is relational, one design that's often used is "star schema" or some variation of it.  This turns out to be enormously convenient for a point-and-shoot or drill-down interface, provided the names of the data elements are meaningful to the relevant people.

You have a lot of learning to do.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your operational database (OLTP) is for storing transaction information. It is highly normalized to prevent anomalies, and for speeding writes. Stuff like patient visit information would be stored here.

You can use the same database to analyze information, but putting it into a less normalized form can make this a lot easier, especially for non DBAs. This would be your analytic database (data warehouse), against which you can perform OLAP operations.

OLAP is a set of operations (like pivot, slice, dice). A data warehouse is database designed to ease analysis. They are different.

I'm don't see how down-time is related to OLTP vs OLAP.

> is it possible that the OLAP is another layer above the centralized
>   database and when analyzing doesn't interfere in the exchange of data
>   between these singular workstations and the central database?

Usually you would extract data from your operational database to your analytic database on a schedule. Just doing selects won't interfere with it. I would say your analytic database is "beside" your operational one, not "above".

> Or does the central database need to be of OLAP architecture itself?

If you are doing transaction processing in your central database, then no.

> Also can an OLTP database store for example data like medical history?

Yes

Comment: Thank you for the fast response :) I've started reading about databases because of this project and I ran accross many websites where OLTP databases were described as very stable and reliable, fast write-read and no down-time, whereas OLAP as slow and some operation could get the whole system down for a while, and it's very important for this central database to be very stable and always up.

Comment: I do see how down time is related to OLTP vs OLAP.